# SSRS: Unable to create a child row group for a single row under a parent row group that spans 2 rows

Tags: reporting-services, grouping, rows

I'm having a pretty wicked problem in SSRS with row groups. I have a tablix in a report that looks like the following:

[image]

I have 2 rows(student name and team averages) that are under a row group currently. However I need to add a child row group under this parent row group for just the row that has student names. This child row group would group all the student names by student name and then at the end of all students for this team, the team averages column would display. When a new team comes up in the data set, it would start the parent row grouping over, etc..

However when I goto try to add a child group to the parent group, I get the error message "Innermost Group Does Not Have a Grouping Cell". Google/searching here didnt produce much in the way of this error message so I'm pretty stuck.

Any advice on how to achieve this parent and child row grouping situation? If you have any questions, please feel free to ask.

Comment: I actually figured this one out -- updating to SP2 of SSRS 2008 fixes this error. It didnt necessarily get the data to group how I wanted but it still fixes this error message.

Comment: looks like the details section has been removed. once the details has gone - it is hard to get it back. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627469.aspx

Comment: http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/527455/error-in-report-designer-innermost-group-does-not-have-a-grouping-cell

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue today, and I was able to fix it by:

1. Deleting all of my existing groups and associated rows & columns.
2. Recreating the groups, allowing it to insert the associated row/column.
3. Then, I went back and removed the associated rows & columns without deleting the group.

I think this happens whenever you have multiple groups without having an associated row/column in the Tablix.